# Get the unique value based on comparing two arrays

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have two array strings that look like this

```
array1 = "January","February","September"
array2 = "January","December","September"
```

Both arrays have the same number of indexes for comparison purposes. What I want to achieve is to display the string "December", since the value of both array indexes did not match each other.

Comment: Do you not want to display December AND February?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the values into an array and use `Except` to find the ones that don't match.

From your description I'm not sure if you want the contents of one that doesn't match the other or all unmatching items, so I have given all options here:

```
    Dim array1 = {"January", "February", "September"}
    Dim array2 = {"January", "December", "September"}

    'Pick one of the following three options
    Dim inFirstButNotSecond = array1.Except(array2) 'Gives February
    Dim inSecondButNotFirst = array2.Except(array1) 'Gives December
    Dim uniqueVals = inFirstButNotSecond.Concat(inSecondButNotFirst) 'Gives February, December
```

The beauty of this is that it doesn't matter how many elements are in each array

Edit:

As requested, to display the non-matching items as a single string in a messagebox you can use `String.Join` on the resultant array like this:

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", array1.Except(array2).Concat(array2.Except(array1))))
```

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate the value of February and December when using Dim uniqueVals = array2.Except(array1).Concat(array1.Except(array2))? Im mean display both February and December in one messagebox.